# Searching text and caching data

Tags: c#, performance

I have a text file that contains 1.5 million lines of text.

Each line has a different sentence.

I also have a single word collection. There are about 2000 of them.

For each word in the collection I want to pick up all the sentences in the collection.

They must be sent separately because everyone will be saved into the database.

**I have a solution that works but is terribly slow:**

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();

List<string> enWordsPage = new List<string>();

var lines = File.ReadAllLines("collection.csv");
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 1)
{
    enWordsPage.Add(lines[i]);
}
enWordsPage = enWordsPage.ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());

for (int i = 1; i <= 2000; i++)
{
    string enWord = db.GetWordById(i);

    foreach (var item in enWordsPage)
    {
        if (item.Contains(enWord))
        {
            string text = "";
            text = item.Trim();

            int idWord = db.GetIdWordByName(enWord);
            db.AddItemToSentences(idWord, text);
        }
    }
}
```

It goes through the loop every time through all the lines.

What can I improve to speed up?

Comment: Are you trying to find all sentences with a word? (trying to understand the question)

Comment: Wouldn't it help to have a dictionary of keywords and list of sentences? something like Dictionary<string, List<string>>. Add an entry in this dictionary for each keyword and add a sentence to the list (value of the keyword) if it is there in the sentence.

Comment: `db.GetIdWordByName(enWord);` as well as `db.AddItemToSentences(idWord, text);` within *nested loops* are the worst enemies

Comment: it is slow because you go through 1,5mil line 2000 times.

Comment: I have to build something like that. The problem is that for each word in the 2000 list it searches all lines in a file that has 1.5 million. At the moment I have to search all lines. Is there any way not to do it and get results without going line by line?

Comment: What should happen in the scenario that a word contains another word. For example "lab" and "labradoodle" should as sentence that contains "labradoodle" also be connected to the word "lab"?

Comment: Load in memory all your special words once.  Read the file lines by lines with stream. For each line, check if the line contains the words store the matching words in a list. Lines should be bigger than list of word in most case. So storing the lines only once, with a list of matching word should be lighter that a list of matching sentence for every word. Once you have that bluk insert into a temp table, And batch the update from temp to real table.

Comment: I feel like there must be a better algorithm. First guess (maybe someone can improve): split source 1.5M into `Dict<string, List<int>>`, a lookup for each word and list containing index of line it appears in. Then iterate over 2000 match words doing lookup in dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I see this as a problem of streaming and complexity.

Inside the for you have a foreach, there you have the complexity N^2. Plus, you are iterating the lines in your `collection.csv` twice, once to populate the `enWordsPage` and second, to check if the words in a line are in the database. You can merge this loops. Finally, I would use StreamReader instead of File.ReadAllLines, to process the lines as they are read.

I will come up with a prototype of these changes, but since I don't have your data, you will have to check for yourself if it is working.

**Edit:**

You can try this code, it should be slightly faster as you do not iterate through 1.5 milion records twice, but I did not reduced the complexity for it. Instead I have change to using an array of strings because iterating through it should be faster than through the list:

```
var dbWords = new string[2000];
for (int i = 1; i <= 2000; i++)
{
    dbWords[i] = db.GetWordById(i); //if something else can be used to read these 2000 words from the database, this time can be reduced even more
}

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("collection.csv"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < dbWords.Length; index++)
        {
            var dbWord = dbWords[index];
            if (line.Contains(dbWord))
            {
                db.AddItemToSentences(index, line.Trim());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I allowed myself to remove the call to `db.GetIdWordByName(enWord)` since at the beginning of your for loop you were using `db.GetWordById(i)` to get the words by ID and your parameter was the index of the loop. If my assumption is right, this would greatly reduce the reads from the database even more.

Comment: A loop inside another is N^2 not 2^N.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate yes, you are right, I corrected it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first circulation after the collection is short. Few seconds. The last loop is the worst. Each loop goes through a long time. Any suggestion for improving the solution will be helpful

Comment: `File.ReadLines()` (without the  `All`) will stream just as well wit less changes. But those lines are buffered, it would only matter for the startup time.

Comment: `db.AddItemToSentences` and `db.GetIdWordByName(dbWords[i])` might be database related. It would be nice that they don't sit in a loop. Or batch them I don't know.  Thats the performance killer. While ReadAllLines is the memory killer

Comment: @DragandDrop I guess you are right, but I assume that as he previously was iterating through a `List` of 1.5 milion records, 2000 times, and now it is iterating through it once, but iterating through an `array` 1.5 milion times, the end result should be faster IMHO. Also, for small arrays, the CPU can do some nice caching.

Comment: @DragandDrop I believe now the implementation should see a change in performance as it does not need one more call to the database

Comment: It is a bit faster but it shows me that it will take such a solution for about 40 hours. I calculated it based on the short code run time

Comment: @DevNet can you use diagnostic tools to profile it and tell me what section of code takes this time?

Comment: @DevNet anyway, as I keep looking over this code, I don't see an immediate way to optimise it right away. Ultimately you can add the elements `index, line.Trim()` to a list and only persist them to the database as a batch, into a single transaction. This way you should get the lowest time possible.